# Secure client-side buttons that control their servers

Tags: node.js, express, security

I am working on a small project where my clients will have a control panel with which they can (obviously) control their gameservers. What bothers me is them sending the request to START/STOP the server. I tend to give the buttons an onclick function that makes a call using ajax, but I don't know if this is the best way to do this.
Right now I pass the users ID and the server's ID and then perform the operation he had requested. 
It seems to me that there must be a better way, but I don't see it yet.

P.S. Currently the REST API for server control doesn't need any authentication. Still not sure how I could implement this without passing their information too much.

Comment: "*Right now I pass the users ID and the server's ID and then perform the operation he had requested.*" then anyone can just issue a network request with those - they can even use `curl` or something, not necessarily a browser. You should *authenticate* any request sent to an endpoint.

Comment: Yes exactly. I know this issue and that is why I am seeking help. I don't know if I should use JWT tokens or a different way of authentication.